# How to detect function creation js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect when a function is created, preferable through a constructor. Functions are a type of object, right? So it makes sense that when you create a new one, it calls a constructor. Is there a way to override this, for example, something like this

```js
var old = Function.constructor;
Function.constructor = () => {
  alert('new function created!');
  old();
};

function asdf() {}

var k = new Function();
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to get all currently defined functions? I am trying to trigger a piece of code on each function run.

Comment: I think this will only detect functions that are created using `new Function()`. When you define functions with `function ...` or `() =>` I don't think it uses the constructor.

Comment: You can get all the functions that are defined in global variables by looping through all the `window` properties. But you won't be able to get local functions, functions that are in class methods, etc.

Comment: Do you have control over the function? You could re-write it to add tracking code and then return the actual implementation

Comment: It sounds like you'll have to modify your JavaScript engine to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect function creation.

> Functions are a type of object, right?

Yes.

> So it makes sense that when you create a new one, it calls a constructor.

No. Or - maybe, but that constructor is internal. Just like the construction of objects from array literals, object literals, regex literals, definition of a function directly creates a native object.

> Is there a way to override this?

No. You'd need to hook into the JS engine itself for that.

> If this is not possible, is there a way to get all currently defined functions?

No. At best, you could try the debugging API of the JS engine and get a heap snapshot, that should contain all function objects.

> I am trying to trigger a piece of code on each function run.

Let me guess, that piece of code is a function itself?

Answer (score -1):

Was able to get a semi-working attempt at this. It reads only global functions but it can add code to both the front and beginning of the function. Any tips on how to improve this, as I use classes a lot when I code?

Thanks to Barmar for the idea of looping through window properties, but since you can't access local functions and class functions, this may be the closest way to do this

```html
<script>
function prepend(name) {
  console.time(name);
}

function postpend(name) {
  console.timeEnd(name);
}

var filter = ['prepend', 'postpend', 'caches'];

function laggyFunction() {
  var l = 0;
  while (l<1000) {l++}
}

var functions = [];
for (var property in window) {
  try {
    if (!filter.includes(property)) { // security error on accessing cache in stackoverflow editor along with maximum call stack size exceeded if prepend and postpend are included
      if (typeof window[property] === 'function') {
        window[property].original = window[property];
        window[property].name = property;
        window[property] = function() {
          prepend(this.name);
          console.log(this.original);
          this.original.apply(null, arguments);
          postpend(this.name);
        }.bind(window[property]);
        functions.push(property);
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.warn(`Couldn't access property: `+property+' | '+e);
  }
}
document.write(functions); // functions the prepend and postpend are applied to

laggyFunction(); // test performance of the function
</script>
```